# Html Page Search Intercept (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, search

If a user views your webpage and presses ctrl+f (chrome) then searches for a word in your page, is there anyway to intercept this search term with javascript?

I want to know this information mostly for analytics, I don't need to modify the behavior of the search.

Thanks

Comment: I do not think you can intercept such event, but I'm unsure about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm, this is cool. I'd never thought about doing that.

<s>Sadly you can't though. You might be able to capture the search string with a plugin, but seeing as this is for analytics it wont get you the result you want.</s>

I tested this in Chrome, and when you press <kbd>ctrl+f</kbd> you will see the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> press, but not <kbd>f</kbd>. So you can't even detect when someone searches.

You **can** detect <kbd>ctrl+f</kbd>. Use `keydown` instead of `keypress`. I found it here:

[Stop browser from auto scrolling when searching document (ctrl + f)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19941641/stop-browser-from-auto-scrolling-when-searching-document-ctrl-f)

```
window.addEventListener("keydown",function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 114 /* F3 */ || (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 70) /* ctrl+f*/ ) { 
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```